# Splitting columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining

I have a dataframe named a with 1 variable having the following structure

```
    Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time 
    Idle                  0   0   4    0      0    13:26:52.515     4:18:08.670
    System                4   8 148 1199   1616     0:10:14.750     4:18:08.670
    smss                388  11   2   49    336     0:00:00.109     4:18:08.597
```

Now I want to split the dataframe into the columns with colnames Name, Pid, Pro, Thd, Hnd and so on.

I tried strsplit:

```
    df<-strsplit(a," ")
```

but the results were like they were splitted into all those characters having a space. 
Please help

```
> dput(a)
c("Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd   Priv        CPU Time    Elapsed Time ", 
"Idle                  0   0   4    0      0    13:26:52.515     4:18:08.670", 
"System                4   8 148 1199   1616     0:10:14.750     4:18:08.670", 
"smss                388  11   2   49    336     0:00:00.109    4:18:08.597" )
```

Comment: These are not columns but a single column separated by spaces.

Comment: On using do.call, it threw up error Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `read.table`

```
  df1 <- read.table(text=a, sep='', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df1 
  #    Name Pid Pri Thd  Hnd
  #1   Idle   0   0   4    0
  #2 System   4   8 148 1199
  #3   smss 388  11   2   49

  str(df1)
  #'data.frame':    3 obs. of  5 variables:
  #$ Name: chr  "Idle" "System" "smss"
  #$ Pid : int  0 4 388
  #$ Pri : int  0 8 11
  #$ Thd : int  4 148 2
  #$ Hnd : int  0 1199 49
```

Suppose the new object is 'a1', we read the lines (`read.table`) without the header line, and then set the column names of the new dataset ('df2') after creating some quotes for "CPU Time" and "Elapsed Time" using `gsub` (to be read as a single string) with `lookarounds` and get the `vector` of words with `scan`

```
  df2 <- read.table(text=a1[-1], sep='', header=FALSE, 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  colnames(df2) <-  scan(text=gsub('(?<=Time)\\s|\\s(?=Elapsed|CPU)',
                "'", a1[1], perl=TRUE), what='', quiet=TRUE)
  df2
  #    Name Pid Pri Thd  Hnd Priv     CPU Time Elapsed Time
  #1   Idle   0   0   4    0    0 13:26:52.515  4:18:08.670
  #2 System   4   8 148 1199 1616  0:10:14.750  4:18:08.670
  #3   smss 388  11   2   49  336  0:00:00.109  4:18:08.597
```

#### data

```
  a <- c("Name                Pid Pri Thd  Hnd",
   "Idle                  0   0   4    0", 
   "System                4   8 148 1199   ", 
  "smss                388  11   2   49    "
  )
```

Comment: I had tried this at first. The problem in this is that I have an element having a space between "CPU Time" and hence getting error. Though the solution you provided is perfectly right as per the question I mentioned

Comment: @BitanshuDas Can you update your post with that example?

Comment: @BitanshuDas If you put 'CPU Time' in single quotes it should work.

Comment: @BitanshuDas Is it a column name?

Comment: @akrun...check now . Its the whole data frame